# Upload XML File to ASP.net Page, Bind Specific Node to GridView (C#)

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, gridview

I am trying to create an ASP.net/C# web page that contains a GridView, and the ability for a user to upload an XML file to that page and bind the grid to a node in that XML. The XML file must be read into memory--not saved to the server first--which has prevented me from modelling this on many online examples which presume an uploaded file is physically sitting on the server when it’s accessed.

The simplified test XML file looks like this, and I do have some latitude to alter or expand it if necessary:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
  <root>
    <Grids>
      <Grid name="GridView">
        <item>
          <Uno>1A</Uno>
          <Dos>1B</Dos>
          <Tres>1C</Tres>
        </item>
        <item>
          <Uno>2A</Uno>
          <Dos>2B</Dos>
          <Tres>2C</Tres>
        </item>
        <item>
          <Uno>3A</Uno>
          <Dos>3B</Dos>
          <Tres>3C</Tres>
        </item>
        <item>
          <Uno>4A</Uno>
          <Dos>4B</Dos>
           <Tres>4C</Tres>
        </item>
      </Grid>
    </Grids>
</root>
```

The client needs to be able to click on a *FileUpload* control, browse to a local XML file, and have the grid reflect the data in the node named "GridView" above. I can’t figure out how to extract just that node from the XML data. If I create a cut-down, poorly formed XML file with that node as the root, it works, but I don’t want to do that as I plan on expanding this in the future.

Below is the salient portion of the ‘import’ code I have at the moment. It’s not optimal – I got here through trial and error so there’s probably a lot of garbage in here. When I run this, I get a single-cell grid that just contains the text “Grid_Id” rather than the tabular data I need (although even that’s broken at the moment).

```
protected void btnImport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
            {
                string fileExt = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(FileUpload1.FileName);
                if (fileExt == ".xml")
                {
                    using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(FileUpload1.FileBytes))     // Using FileBytes because I can’t save file to server
                    {
                        XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();
                        document.Load(stream);
                        stream.Position = 0;
                        string xmlFile;
                        using (StreamReader inputStreamReader = new StreamReader(FileUpload1.PostedFile.InputStream))
                        {
                            xmlFile = inputStreamReader.ReadToEnd();
                        }
                        XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(new StringReader(xmlFile));

                        DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
                        dataSet.ReadXml(reader);

                        //gv1.DataSource = dataSet.Tables[“GridView”];  // Doesn’t work
                        gv1.DataSource = dataSet.Tables[0];
                        gv1.DataBind();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Ultimately I’d like to create a more generic component that will allow us to any save grid data to a user’s desktop and push that ‘snapshot’ back in to the grid at a later date. Thanks in advance for any guidance (this is my first post)!

Comment: when you use the debugger.. you will see that the dataSet.Tables has 3 tables so you probably are looking to do this for your datagrid

`gv1.DataSource = dataSet.Tables[2];
 gv1.DataBind();` you need to understand the current structure of the .xml file it yields 3 separate DataTables when you do the dataSet.ReadXml method

Comment: Thank you! I thought I had tried different indices, but setting it to "2" does bring up the data in the grid. Strangely it also creates a fourth column with the heading "Grid_Id" and zeros in the column... I'll have to figure out why that is next. But this was very helpful, thanks!

Comment: I would look at the source in regards to what's generating the XML file.. there are ways to fix your issue but you would need to write few lines of code.

Comment: Two thoughts: 1st, I checked the upload XML and it's just as shown in the example above. So that extra column is definitely being added upon "import" somewhere along the way.

Comment: 2nd, while using the "dataset.tables[2]" gets me much closer, I'd still love to be able to grab that portion of the dataset by name rather than index, but I guess I'm puzzled by how the XML gets stored as nested tables within the dataset. Maybe a LINQ query against the dataset could extract just that table into a new recordset I could bind to instead? Trying to pull out the data for the single GridView by name seems to grab the parent, even when I tried renaming the elements. I'm puzzled by this.

Comment: you should be able to grab by name use the debugger and you will see that when you use the dropdown.. you will see the name based on the 4 different nodes

Comment: I've tried rewording several ways, but when I bind to the XML at the 'record' level ["item" in above XML], an extra column keeps showing up, the name of which is the name of the parent of the records plus "_Id" [like "Grid_Id"], and the fields in it are all zeros. I just don't understand what is generating this phantom column. It doesn't exist in the XML file.

Comment: if you are having issues with formatting your xml perhaps you need to read up on how to create and format xml.. I would really like to know where you are getting this xml from and if you are loading it from a file then you have to inspect the datatable results for each datatable column by column and match it up with the XML and see if you are missing something somewhere you have a formatting issue or perhaps this is formatted correctly and you need to write code to not use that column data or look at how to use the merge method of the datatable to get the columns / data into a single datatable

Comment: why are you using a `MemoryStream` to read the XML File when all you need to do is know the file location / Path then this line at the bottom
`dataSet.ReadXml(file, XmlReadMode.InferSchema);`
I use 3 lines of code to do what you are doing in 8 lines try using the example here that Infers the Xml Schema.... also you can get the file path after your extension check passes using 
`var file = Path.GetFilePath(@FileUpload1.FileName);`